# Source queue message retention period is greater than dead letter queue

Tags: amazon-web-services

**Scenario**
A message is picked from the queue and processed by the application, during which I got an exception which leads to queue level retries and finally message moved to Dead Letter Queue(DLQ).

After certain amount of time (4h), the messages in the DLQ are redriven and post to the source queue itself.

**Question**

1. I got the same error again and the message again moved to DLQ. Whether it is considered as new message or not?
2. I have retention period of source queue by default(4d) where as the retention period of DLQ (1d). What is the effect of this configuration?